# Can I get notifications in the Ubuntu app tray?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Basically I am a power user, and I want to help the Ubuntu community more quickly, while continuing to develop the parts of the platform that I find lacking. To do this with maximum efficiency I want to use the notification area to display notifications from this site.

How can I get the Notifications to show up in the corner the way that empathy and wifi show up?

Comment: This actually sounds like a question for the main site!

Comment: you mean smth like this http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-large-scale ?

Comment: exactly so, but surely the stack people have a slightly more ready solution?

Comment: @TreyGordon Why would they?  Their target is the web interface and mobile apps, I doubt they are going to stand up and make a notification applet to run on the Ubuntu or Windows or Mac dash or task bar or notifier bar when one already exists made third party and works for the most part.